# What size start capacitor should I buy for my refrigerator compressor?

Tags: hvac, refrigerator, cooling, compressor

What size (in horsepower) 3-in-1 start capacitor should i buy for my fridge compressor?  I have an LG LRSC26922TT from 2003. The compressor isnt staying on due to (i think the PTC hooked to the compressor). So i am eliminating the capacitors on top and the ptc on the compressor and putting a Supco 3-in-1 start capacitor in. I tried to upload pics but my phone is giving me crap. The nameplate inside says 3.5 amps in general. I'm trying to find out how much horsepower the compressor is by taking volts x amps = watts. And Watts ÷ 745.7 = horsepower ...anyone know the amp rating of the compressor at surge or continuous? OR the horsepower of the compressor? I can choose between 1/4 - 1/3 hp OR just 1/2 hp.

Comment: There should be a tag on the fridge or compressor that states the RLA , the reason for shutdown could be many other reasons, overheating the thermal overload on the motor, high head pressure, low pressure. Modern systems have more problems that are Freon based causing high temps and low head pressures. The cost of caps might be what an inexpensive volt meter that has a capacitance tester, most caps are in the 15-30 up to 150UF (micro fared) range. A ohm meter can be used to check charge discharge rates for a cap rather than throwing parts at it. It could be something as simple as a thermostat.

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? If so, please give a check-mark to the answer that helped you the most, or write up your own answer explaining what you did to get it fixed and give yourself a check mark. That will help others with this kind of problem know that this has a resolution and is a good place to look for their answer

Answer (score 0):

What is the PTC?    For the horsepower, you need to add in the power factor which is somewhere around 75% and use the input watts of +/- 1000 not the 745.7 figure you used. Is the compressor a psc which uses a capacitor all the time. What is a Supco 3 in 1 start capacitor? You have a lot of variables you need to consider. If you are not exactly sure what you are doing call a service tech or continue to play " Russian roulette"

Answer (score 0):

If my guess is correct I think it will be around 15uf, however that said I see one capacitor is 100mfd, and the other 14mfd. (looking at parts online) . The entire overload and capacitor Run/Start setup is in the SUPCO package.

Looking [online at the Supco 0410 type](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000LDB89S) - it works with most refrigerators.  I can not say specific to your model I think you will be fine at 1/4 hp but check out [Supco URCO410 - this is light commercial but tells the compressor types in app details.](http://www.supco.com/web/supco_live/products/URCO410RC.html)